# apex file Error: Failed to parse wsdl: schema:targetNamespace can not be null

Tags: apex, soap, wsdl2apex

I am having a wsdl document developed in .net framework. I am trying to create  New Apex Code from that WSDL document but I am keep getting errors. I have resolved couple of them and now am getting a weird one.

**Error: Failed to parse wsdl: schema:targetNamespace can not be null**

How can I resolved all my wsdl document errors.

Here is my WSDL 
goo.gl/awMRto

Comment: Can you share the source WSDL?

Comment: Here it is goo.gl/awMRto

Answer (score 2):

That WSDL only has a SOAP 1.2 address defined in the `wsdl:service`.

WSDL2Apex requires a SOAP 1.1 port type to function. If the WSDL had both Soap 1.1 and 1.2 it would be possible to get it to work, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

You will need to manually create the SOAP requests from Apex and parse the responses.

Also, vote for the Idea: [Support for SOAP 1.2](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroS). I'd be extremely surprised if it ever happened, but you never know.

---

For what it's worth, that specific error is coming from the `xs:schema` that is missing the `targetNamespace` attribute. That attribute is used to drive the name of the Apex class that will contain the elements defined in the namespace.

However, as noted above, even if you alter this you won't get much further due to the SOAP 1.2 incompatibility.

```
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="DataSet" nillable="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <ActualType Name="DataSet" Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>
                    <xs:any/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the manual call to SOAP.

Comment: @maxspan Do you have control of the web service? If so, you could add soap 1.1 support there.

Comment: Yes I have control over web service

Comment: Here is the SOAP 1.1 
https://tinyurl.com/ydy2j44k

Comment: @maxspan There are further challenges for working from Apex. For instance, the `GetNewStatusUpdatesResult` element doesn't define a type. And it contains its own schema and `xs:any`. The latter not being supported by Wsdl2Apex either. Avoid returning DataSets if you want to use the methods in Apex. Return something strongly typed.

Comment: I am getting a error Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location https://apitest.integrapay.com.au/basic/PayLinkService.svc?xsd=xsd0. External schema import not supported. IF I comment out all the <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports"> it allows me to go the next page but on generation throw Apex Generation Failed
Unable to find schema for element; {http://tempuri.org/}PayerSavePaymentMethodResponse

Comment: @maxspan The native version of WSDL2Apex doesn't support `xsd:import`. It needs to be a single file WSDL. Change the `?WSDL` at the end of the URL to `?singleWSDL`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61909/discussion-between-maxspan-and-daniel-ballinger).